# TestWatcher API, junit5, Allure: how to take a browser when @AfterEach happens earlier than testFailed

Tags: java, ui-automation, junit5, allure

I have only started to work with Junit5/Selenium and Allure

As all of you and I know that TestWatcher APIs work ONLY after JUnit annotations like @AfterAll/Each for example.

But my problem is that I need to take a screenshot when a test is failed.
Yes, I can add closing browser to TestWatcher:

```java
@Override
public void testFailed(ExtensionContext extensionContext, Throwable throwable) {
    Allure.addAttachment("Attachment",
        new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) browser.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)));
    if (getBrowser().isBrowserAlive()) {
        Browser.getInstance().close();
    }
}
```

but I don't like it - because I need to add closing browsers to each method of TestWatcher. And in a result, an attachment will be added to the body to allure test.

But I want to add closing browser to:

```java
@AfterEach
void tearDown() {}
```

Question: how from BaseTest class send a driver to TestWatcher (testFailed).

I found code like this - but unfortunately for me no idea how to use it because in test class I don't have a driver:

```java
Object test = extensionContext.getRequiredTestInstance();
Field field = test.getClass().getDeclaredField("driver");
field.setAccessible(true);
WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) field.get(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a getter method for the driver in Test class, which will allow you to do the following:

```
WebDriver driver = test.getClass().getDriver();
```